# RDS MySQL instance is unavailable, probably during binlog rotation

Tags: mysql, aws

One of my customers uses a few EC2 linuxes with PHP application, connected to a standalone MySQL RDS.
He reported application outage. During my investigation  I found that this outage happened immediately after  some RDS operation with mysql binlogs, probably log rotation.
Is there some known issue?[image: CloudWatch "binary log disk usage" is attached]

Update: Many thanks to Rolando and Maxime. I have a few years of MySQL experience; but I'm pretty new @ AWS. So my question in fact: "is there some RDS-specific issue with MySQL binlog processing which causes to DB outage?"

Comment: Please run `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'expire_logs_days';` and `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'max_binlog_size';` on the RDS instance and tell us the output.

Comment: expire_logs_days | 0
max_binlog_size | 134217728

Comment: This wouldn't happen to coincide with your configured [RDS maintenance window](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/AdjustingTheMaintenanceWindow.html) would it?

Comment: no, there is no correlation with my RDS maintenance window

Answer (score 1):

Your graph shows a binary log purge launched at approximatively 4am the 23th.

You can search for a query like:

```
PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE '2014-04-23 04:00:00';
-- or
PURGE MASTER LOGS BEFORE '2014-04-23 04:00:00';
```

If you are sure that your **MySQL** is a standalone instance, there is no know issues with the `PURGE BINARY LOGS` statement and I see that your binary log is 1.5Mb so i'm sure your system can manage that purge without pain. In a Master/Slave infrastructure, you can purge binary logs before they been "played" on slaves, the result is the slaves replication goes down (with impact on the apps).

Max.